# get a specific string in C# and trim the value

Tags: c#

Hi I would like to trim a string

`IWF01 - STSD Campus   |   1009432   |   Posted Today`

I need to get this string `1009432`.
Or something like this

`ROS03 - Roseville, CA R-3, More...   |   T_R_1624621   |   Posted Today`

I want to get this one  `T_R_1624621`.

How do I get that part of string only?

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Comment: what is the rule in you example for the choice of the element? this is a very decisive point! please don't make the people guess, just to find out in the end that a third example is different from what one thought in the first place.

Comment: because every ID is unique and different that's why I included the second, I still don't have any codes yet for this

Comment: "every ID is unique" there is no information in your post that there is an ID anywhere. " I included the second" do you mean that the selection rule is take always the second? or you included the second example to show that the chosen element can be different? Is it possible that the element can be situated at the third position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "ROS03 - Roseville, CA R-3, More... | T_R_1624621 | Posted Today";
var strArr = s.Split('|');
string yourValue = strArr[1].Trim();
```

Beware, this can cause some exceptions. If you don't have right string (that can be splitted by `|`, or if you have string that has only one `|` etc...

Comment: This one works flawlessly Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is split the string, then I'd get the 2nd item (provided that there are enough items).

Here's a function that'll do what you need (remember that it won't raise an exception if there aren't enough items):

```
string GetFieldTrimmed(string input, char separator, int fieldIndex)
{
    var strSplitArray = input.Split(separator);
    return strSplitArray.Length >= fieldIndex + 1 
        ? strSplitArray[fieldIndex].Trim() 
        : "";
}
```

Example usage:

```
var fieldVal = GetFieldTrimmed("ROS03 - Roseville, CA R-3, More... | T_R_1624621 | Posted Today", '|', 1);
```